# Couchbase lite .net multiple keys

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

Maybe I am not the first to ask this question, but I could not find an answer to this problem yet.
I have created a view which emits multiple keys:

```
ParametersByTestCase.SetMap(
(doc, emit) =>
{
if (!doc[“Type”].ToString().Equals(TestCaseModel.TYPE)) return;
var keys = new List<object>
{
doc["_id"],
doc[“TestDefId”]
};
emit(keys, doc[“Params”]);
},
“1.0”);
```

Now i would like to query for a certain key but I do not get any result. From the forum I found this solution:

```
var key = new List { testDefId };
var keys = new List<object> { key };
query.Keys = keys;
query.Run();
```

which always returns no result (and the key is definitely in the index).

another approach i found was this:

```
query.StartKey = new List<object> { testDefId };
query.EndKey = new List<object> { testDefId, new Dictionary<string, object>() };
query.Run();
```

which also does not work… what am i doing wrong?

Ty & BR
Hannes

Answer (score 1):

## First

have you tryed without keys or (startkey and endkey) to see if you become something?

## Why it cannot work

Ps : based on the collation principle your query with start endkey cannot work because the first element of your liste should be the doc._id otherwise the response will be empty.

https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation

for the keys query you have the same pb. the first one should be doc._id
The problem is that you declare a key like this new List(){ "a", "b"} so in the keys you should write something like this new List(){ new List(){"a", "b"}}}.
The key is a list of 2 elements, the should should be a list of keys (which are list)

## example that should work (not tested after i have rewrite it to be able to post it)

```
var view = database.GetView("spongbob");
view.SetMap((doc, emit) =>
{
if (doc["Type"] == "spongbob")
{
emit(new object[]{ doc["_id"],doc["strength"] }, doc);
}
}, "1.0");
```